# How to write comment in fastlane file

Tags: android, ruby, fastlane

im tryng to comment some line in my fastline but im not sure how to write comment in fastlane files. also i dont want to remove the lines.

here's what i think:

```
build(variant: 'Release')
appcenter_upload(
  api_token: ENV['APPCENTER_API_TOKEN'],
  owner_name: "Ralali.com",
  app_name: "Ralali-Android",
  apk: "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
  destinations: "Production",
  # destination_type: "group",   IS THIS LINE COMMENTED? (WON'T EXECUTED?)
  # notify_testers: true         AND ALSO THIS ONE
)
```

I run fastlane with circleci in production and i dont wan't to try in in production because im afraid.

Comment: yes  #  is for comments

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use # for single-line comment and =begin ... =end for multi-line comment. Also, note that the =begin and =end must be at the beginning of the line or
it will be a syntax error.

```
# Single-line comment

=begin
Multi-line
comment
=end
```